# Flex ExternalInterface callback

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Flex:

```
public function callFromJavaScript():String
{
       test.label='dfdsfsdf';
       return "1";
}
public function init():void {
       ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToFlash", callFromJavaScript);
}
```

HTML

```
<object classid='clsid:x-x-x-x-x' height='200px' width='300px'>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name='src' value='${swf}.swf'/>
        <embed  name='mySwf' id='qwe' src='${swf}.swf' height='200px' width='300px'/>
</object>
```

I know there are multiple (JavaScript) methods like:
`document.getElementById('FlexAppId').setName(name);`

However:

1. I have no clue which one are crossbrowser compatible (cant install IE to test out)
2. I have tried multiple but I can't get them to work(in any browser), I'm probably using the wrong id, I've been trial & erroring for a couple of hours but I don't have anything working.
   (I heard there was a problem with ExternalInterface.addCallback on a local file system?, should I upload the swf? < is the flex code right& problem = JavaScript/html side?)

Comment: View the example, it's a good starting point: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to manipulate the HTML that's hosting your Flash in some way, or are you trying to invoke a callback in your Flash from JavaScript?

Comment: make sure your `object` and `embed` tags have the same id parameter (this your case it looks like `qwe`. then try: `document.getElementById('qwe').callFromJavaScript()`;

Comment: also, fire up the JS console in your browser and check for any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExternalInterface` functions are know to have issues across browsers and operating systems. Some of the recommendations are,

1. User `swfobject` or any other standard library to `embed` your swf. ([swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/))
2. Use 'allowscriptaccess=always'
3. Give proper `id` and `name` to the embed tag
4. `id` and `name` attribute should be always same.
5. If your swf file is coming from a different domain than the html page, use `Security.AllowDomain('domain-of-html-page.com')`

Comment: Regarding #5, also make sure you have a crossdomain.xml file in place on each domain.