# Flex4 desktop application, write in html5, how to call fx-script in javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a simple project written in html + javascript, how to package it in `flex4`, I need to call `flex File API` in javascript, but seems not work, so how to implement it ?
[image][image]
`<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSWFObject(movieName)
    {
        if(document[movieName])
        {
            return document[movieName];
        }else if(window[movieName]){
            return window[movieName]; 
        }else if(document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName]){
            return document.embeds[movieName];
        }else{
            return document.getElementById(movieName);
        }
    }
    getSWFObject("test40").callback1();`

Comment: May i know where this JS method is implemented and how you flex app is embedded? Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e92.html

Comment: make sure your browser have java script enabled- refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390244/flex-externalinterface-callback